Unable to Access Node.js Application on Internet deployed under SAP BTP Kyma Environment
I have deployed a Node.js application in the SAP BTP Kyma environment. I have enabled Istio sidecar injection in my namespace and created an API Rule to expose my service to the internet. However, I am unable to access my application.
Here are the steps i have followed:
1.Enabled Istio Sidecar Injection:
"kubectl label namespaces  istio-injection=enabled"
2.Created API Rule:
here i have attached the apirule.yaml
3.Service Configuration:
here is my service.yaml
4.Tried to verify the istio injection using the following command,
"istioctl experimental check-inject -n  "
5.I got the following response that "The injection webhook is deactivated, and will never match           labels".
response
Questions:
1.Is there anything I am missing or doing incorrectly in the setup?
2.How can I troubleshoot why the sidecar injection might not be working correctly?
3.Are there additional steps required to expose my application to the internet in the Kyma environment?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include the YAML files, error output, and any other required source code in plain text?  Also remember that Stack Overflow questions need to be about programming specifically; if this is more about setting up Istio correctly, another site like [sf] or [devops.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask.
